# How do I get the proper path?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using kotlin and Can't seem to get a proper directory path from an onActivityResult OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Im using this

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.also { uri ->
val selectedDirectory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri) ?: return
                // Get the primary external storage directory
                val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                val storagePath = storageDir.absolutePath
                val path = storagePath + "/" + selectedDirectory.name
```

storagepath gives me /storage/emulated/0 which is what I wan't, and selectedDirectory.name gives me the folder name, but I'm missing all the folders in between. for example if I want /storage/emulated/0/Download/test I'll get /storage/emulated/0/test. Is there anyway I can have path = full path?

Comment: Simply [uri.path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPath())

Comment: I had that originally,  it gave tree/primary:Download/test which did not work.  It has to come back as /storage/emulated/0/Download/test to work

Comment: There is no path. There is no requirement for the document tree to represent a directory on the filesystem.

Comment: Are you saying that's why I'm getting tree/primary? Is there no way to have path return what I need?

Comment: val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                val storagePath = storageDir.absolutePath

                val path = storagePath + "/" + uri.lastPathSegment?.replace("primary:", "")

gets me very close but the replace adds a space

Comment: Nevermind that was the correct answer.  Once I get to a pc I'll set it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the correct answer.

```
val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() val storagePath = storageDir.absolutePath val path = storagePath + "/" + uri.lastPathSegment?.replace("primary:", "")
```